# C - fgets read past newline

Tags: arrays, file, input, fgets, fgetc

I am trying to read a file in increments of 10 and store them in an array. I use a loop to read like this:

```
char storeArray[11];

while(!foef(input)){
    fgets(storeArray, 11, input);
}
```

I need to store 10 characters at a time in the array but fgets stops reading at newline. Any suggestions on how I can continue to read a newline, store it and continue to read until the array is full?

Should I instead use fgetc in a for loop that runs 10 times?

Comment: So this works as I intended it to using fgetc in a for loop. Can someone still explain how it would work with fgets?

Comment: Although you can hammer it hard enough to fit, fgets is designed to handle variable-length lines. **fread** is designed to read fixed-size blocks of data, almost exactly what you want. Also feof() and ferror() are only set *after* an input function returns error so testing before *only* reading in a loop is a small waste but easily leads to testing before reading *and using* either in a loop or not which is dangerously wrong.

Comment: Thanks I'll try out fread. So you would suggest like a do while sort of format where you read first and then check end of file?